# Error with multiple for loop with if statement

Tags: r, function, output, regression

I am trying to create a function in R that will produce a table of results from uni-variate and multivariate regression models

[image: Model Output Table]
Please see my function code below:

```
loganalmv<- function(preds, preds2, resp, data){

    #create empty variables

    uni<- NA
    unic<- NA
    mvc<- NA
    r<- NA

    #create models
    mv<- loganal(preds, resp, data)
for(i in 1:length(preds)){
    preds[i]<- preds2[i]
    uni[i]<- loganaluni(preds[i], resp, data)


#create loop to call model information and create table rows
    for(j in 1:length(uni[[i]][[1]][[1]]$Text)){
        for(k in 1:length(mv[[1]][[1]]$Text)){
    #univariate models

        unic1[j]<-uni[[i]][[1]][[1]]$Text[j]    #Coef name
        unic2[j]<-uni[[i]][[1]][[2]]$Text       #n
        unic3[j]<-uni[[i]][[1]][[3]]$Text[j]    #OR
        unic4[j]<-uni[[i]][[1]][[4]]$Text[j]    #CI
        unic5[j]<-uni[[i]][[1]][[5]]$Text[j]    #P-value

    #multivariate model

        mvc1[k]<- mv[[1]][[1]]$Text[k]  #Coef name
        mvc2[k]<- mv[[1]][[2]]$Text     #n
        mvc3[k]<- mv[[1]][[3]]$Text[k]  #OR
        mvc4[k]<- mv[[1]][[4]]$Text[k]  #CI
        mvc5[k]<- mv[[1]][[5]]$Text[k]  #P-value

    #create rows
        if (!is.na(unic1[j]) || !is.na(mvc1[k])) {
            if(!is.na(unic1[j]) == !is.na(mvc1[k])){    #If the covariate names match add multivariate data
                r[j] <- cbindTable(unic1, unic2, unic3, unic4, unic5, '', mvc2[k], mvc3[k], mvc4[k], mvc5[k], '')   #last is comments column
             }else{
                            #if not put '-' in multivariate columns
                r[j] <- cbindTable(unic1, unic2, unic3, unic4, unic5, '', rep('-', 5), '')  
                }

    #combine rows
            }
    out<- rbindTable(r[j])
     }  
    }
}
    #print table

    return(out)
}
```

`preds` is the group of covariates to call individually

`preds2` is the group of covariates to call in the multivariate model. In this example I have used:

```
demog <- c("gpid", "age")
```

`resp` is the response variable, `data` is my dataframe, `loganaluni` is the univariate function to create a glm model, `loganal` is the multivariate glm model function.

When I call my function:

```
    loganalmv(demog,demog, 'excepted', anal)

I get this output

> loganalmv(demog, demog, 'excepted', anal)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]]$Text
[1] "age "   "gpid C" "gpid D" "gpid E"


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]]$Text
[1] 354 354 354 354


[[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[3]]$Text
[1] "1.05"  "1.81"  "1.70"  "17.26"


[[1]][[4]]
[[1]][[4]]$Text
[1] "(1.02, 1.08)"   "(0.82, 3.99)"   "(0.19, 15.22)"  "(2.21, 135.04)"


[[1]][[5]]
[[1]][[5]]$Text
[1] "< 0.001" "0.141"   "0.636"   "0.007"  


[[1]][[6]]
[[1]][[6]]$Text
[1] ""


[[1]][[7]]
[[1]][[7]]$Text
[1] 354


[[1]][[8]]
[[1]][[8]]$Text
[1] "1.04"


[[1]][[9]]
[[1]][[9]]$Text
[1] "(1.02, 1.07)"


[[1]][[10]]
[[1]][[10]]$Text
[1] "0.002"


[[1]][[11]]
[[1]][[11]]$Text
[1] ""
```

I would expect there to be data for 'gpid B' uni-variate model in rows 1:5 and also data from the multivariate model in rows 6 to 11 for the gpid levels - only age is as shown here.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" means either unic1 or mvc1 is actually NA in this if statement. Check that none of the values is NA by another if (is.na(unic1) || is.na(mvc1)) { ...take action here...} before testing if unic1 and mvc1 are equal.

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html

Comment: Your current code is very hard to read/debug/generalize. Would it be an option for you to write a custom function extracting everything you need from a certain model object, and applying that to all your models?

Comment: Thank you all @kilron - this removes the original error thank you.

Comment: @zx8754 - I haven't heard of this package however it may not be quite what I am looking for - will be useful in other work though thank you!

Comment: @Heroka This is what I am trying to do with this function - apologies if it is not clear

Comment: I have updated the code a little however now I am missing one level of 'gpid' and the ouput is not as I expected - please see edited question

Comment: @pawsmc you don't need to apologize to me, sorry if I appeared snarky. I meant that this is also hard to read/debug for you, and you're doing some things manually that have built-in, vectorized counterparts in R. Would you like an example?

Comment: @Heroka Yes please :)

Comment: @pawsmc see my answer. I think it'll give an idea of what I mean/what these kind of custom functions can look like. For inspiration. And science.

Comment: Deleted answer as not what was required :)